# Visual Studio 2017 - Xamarin shows device as Android Version 7.99 instead of 8.0

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to debug a Xamarin App on my Google Pixel with Android 8.0 installed. When I deploy, Xamarin says it is Google Pixel (Android 7.99).

When I debug, it says unable to connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned 0

Are these two related? How can I fix? I've reinstalled drivers, installed the latest SDKs, restarted ADB server, and still have this issue.

Comment: `Xamarin.Android` API26 is not officially supported *yet*, we are using a custom build right now but to build/debug 7.1 on a Oreo beta device make sure that your android sdk platform tools are updated to 26+ (currently `26.0.0`) and sdk tools are 26+ (currently `26.0.2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7.99 refers to an unreleased version. It will change to 8.0 when it's released. Xamarin.iOS does a similar item with their releases:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.99/ (Notice the note of "preview")

As for the bug, this is a known issue with Visual Studio on Windows and Android Oreo devices:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56740

Visual Studio for Mac does not experience this issue, so you could workaround that problem by using a Mac temporarily. Otherwise just use a non-Oreo device/emulator until we get this fixed.

For a future note to help save you time, use our [Bugzilla repository](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/) and paste the error you are seeing. i.e. `unable to connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned 0`. If there's an existing issue, you can comment on it, and if there is not, feel free to file a bug and our teams will assist you as soon as we can!